# Button being held down detection in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to find a way to check if a button is pressed and held
WITHOUT having to declare a variable myself

If i was declaring a variable the code would look like this-

```
from tkinter import *

pressed=False

def timer(t=0):
    global lbl
    global pressed

    if pressed==False:
        lbl.configure(text=t)
        t += 1

    lbl.after(500,lambda:timer(t))

def hold(event=None):
    global pressed
    pressed=True

def rel(event=None):
    global pressed
    pressed=False
window=Tk()

btn=Button(text='hold to stop timer')
btn.pack()
btn.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',hold)
btn.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',rel)

lbl=Label(text='-')
lbl.pack()

timer()
window.mainloop()
```

but since I need it without the variable `pressed` the code should look something like this-

```
from tkinter import *

def timer(t=0):
    global lbl
    global pressed

    if < CONDITION HERE >
        lbl.configure(text=t)
        t += 1

    lbl.after(500,lambda:timer(t))

window=Tk()

btn=Button(text='hold to stop timer')
btn.pack()

lbl=Label(text='-')
lbl.pack()

timer()
window.mainloop()
```

does the Button() have any method or property I can use to check whether or not the button is being held?
and hence use that in the `< CONDITION HERE >` ?

preferably, I need this to work with a Scale() and check whether or not a scale is being pressed
(I am a newbie so please try not to use over complicated methods )

Comment: Why do you need to do this without a variable?

Comment: @BryanOakley It's kind of difficult to explain
but in short terms, I'm working on a different project
and I need to use the least amount of variables in order to avoid confusion
also if i do add a variable i will have to make a lot of modification to the old code
which will create even more confusion